# What is the difference between LCD/DLP/HD Projectors?

Tags: lcd, projector

What are the differences between LCD/DLP/HD projectors?

Which one would you recommend to hook up to a computer to do light-duty projection - e.g. light video, web-browsing, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would buy an DLP over LCD. That is because I have very good experiences with DLPs. However, either one will do for what you need. You also think ahead when buying an item like this. Plan for what you might use it in the future. Not just for what you need or want at the moment.

Get it from an expert: [DLP and LCD Projector Technology Explained -- Project Point](http://www.projectorpoint.co.uk/ProjectorLCDvsDLP.htm)

#### Quick Review of Disadvantages and Advantages of each... [*Reference*](http://www.projectorreviews.com/advice/dlpvslcd/index.php)

LCD Projectors: Strengths
- Richer color dynamics for better results in rooms with ample ambient light
- Draw less power
- Throw less heat
- No color filter wheel = No "rainbow effect"
- Slightly quieter Seemingly sharper image on data

DLP Projectors: Strengths
- Smoother video
- Smaller box
- Pixels far less visible, (although normally not an issue for business use)
- More “filmlike” on DVD and HDTV
- Generate "blacker" blacks 
- Higher contrast

LCD Projectors: Disadvantages
- More visible pixels
- Some screen door effect on certain video images
- Physically larger - Even for the same number of lumens
- Poorer contrast
- Blacks come out lighter gray than DLP projectors

DLP Projectors: Disadvantages
- Rainbow effect bothers some
- More moving parts (color filter wheel)
- Color filter wheel often produces soft but audible whine
- Poorer reds and yellows at full power
- Color saturation
- Need more lumens than LCD, for rich colors, when dealing with ambient light

Answer (score 2):

LCD and DLP are different technologies that basically do the same job.

HD just means high definition - some projectors are high definition (like your computer screen or most new TVs) some aren't (like your DVD player or a very old computer screen).

When buying a projector, the most important considerations are:

- Native Resolution (how sharp the picture is, you probably want at least e.g. *1280 x 720* or *1024 x 768* for web browsing - higher is sharper)
- Brightness (e.g.: *2000 Lumens* can be seen pretty clearly in a somewhat lit room but looks best in a dark one, higher is brighter)
- Contrast (e.g.: *2000:1* - higher is sort of "clearer" or more "realistic". Good plasmas have millions:1 contrast ratios, so projectors aren't fabulous at this - though they work well in a dark room.)